# multiply two layer of tensor with different sizes

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I want to multiply two layer as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import * 
import tensorflow as tf
scale_, mean_ = 2., 4.
a = Input(shape=(128,128), name='Input_vec')
m_num = Input(shape=(4,), name='Input_num')
output = Lambda(lambda x: tf.multiply(x[0], x[1]))((a, m_num[1]))
```

but I always get the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 128 and 4 for '{{node lambda_5/Mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](Placeholder, Placeholder_1)' with input shapes: [?,128,128], [4].
```

Comment: Are you aware that matrix multiplication is not valid if some dimension constraints are not met? This is a mathematical issue, you cannot override this with code.

Comment: yes I know. I want to multiply the matrix a with only the first element of matrix m_num. I could not find how should I extract the elements of this tensor in Tensorflow.

Comment: @Momo is your input (`128`) an image? if so, is it gray or rgb?

Comment: @Innat Yes, It is an image.

Comment: Here is maybe a better explanation: I try to get some some parameters from image and using them create a matrix for next layer. In the image in below you may see my rough idea. So I want to multiply each set of params to image. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U6oEAuTGscujR6HGtlpe976ssjZZr14q/view